# yfrog API to pull in photos to website

Tags: imageshack, yfrog

I have a yfrog account and would like to pull in those posted photos to a gallery on my site, but I can't find any info about pulling in photos - only posting photos.

Is this an available function of the yfrog API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [yfrog API to pull in photos to website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652864/). It seems like you should be able to pull all the photos from a specific yfrog account with this.